# How are the minimum X, maximum X, minimum Y and maximum Y coordinates calculated for a state's county?

Tags: gps

I am working with the eBird API. The eBird website is where birders from around the world enter lists of species for a specific location.

The one API endpoint I was trying to work with returns data with a location name ("Wendy Park Reservation" or "Highland Cemetery" for examples) and GPS coordinates. But, it does not return a county name. So, I have been trying to figure out how to get a county name from the GPS coordinates for the report I am trying to produce using the API.

I found another endpoint in the API that gives regional information. The region I am interested in is a county. 
I was able to get the minimum X, maximum X, minimum Y and maximum Y coordinates for each county in Ohio using this.

So, when I get a set of data back for a location, I use the GPS coordinates and see if they are greater then the min X and less than the max X, and also greater than the min Y and less than the max Y for a specific county's regional information. If they are, then that location is in that county. I set up a JavaScript program to do this. It works.

So, my question is: How does this work? How are the min X, max X, min Y and max Y coordinates calculated for a county?
My brain thinks: "These min/max coordinates have to correspond to a rectangular region." But, few counties are rectangular.

See the example of data below. This is for Cuyahoga County, Ohio.

```
["Cuyahoga", {
    'minX': -81.9712509999999,
    'maxX': -81.374603,
    'minY': 41.274688,
    'maxY': 41.63168
}]
```

Comment: Your javascript program doesn't work correctly. It just appears to because it gets the right county *most* of the time.

Comment: So, are these min/max coordinates a rectangular area inside the county's borders? If a location is in an area that sticks out into another county, the min/max won't surround it?

Comment: No, it's the opposite. The extent is a rectangle, but it is not contained within the county boundaries, it is the minimum rectangle that contains all of the county. So you can have points that are within the min/max extent of a county but not within the county.

Comment: Please tell us the names of "the one API endpoint" and of "another endpoint". I assume you are using eBird API 2.0? https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/664302/ebird-api-20/2HTbHW

Comment: Okay, this doesn't answer your question as defined above, but couldn't you use [`GET Nearest Hotspot`](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/664302/ebird-api-20/2HTbHW#2da513c0-e74d-4990-4fe7-5b08ee2470f7) to retrieve the county given latlng coordinates?

Comment: There is a Regional endpoint to get/request all counties from the US. It returns the counties' min/max. I printed it to a file using Python3 and copied the Ohio info for my JavaScript.   

Other endpoints returned GPS coordinates for a location: recent species in a region and notable species in a region.

For recent species in a region you can use a county code to get species in that county. But, since the JS httpRequest is ansynchronous, I cannot display headers on the page. The headers all get displayed, and then the species data gets displayed.

Comment: I need some way to return a county code/name with the individual species data in order to display the county name. If I could get the code, I could easily set up arrays and use the code's index to get the name in the other array. If you want to discuss the eBird API 2.0 somewhere, please add a link to that forum. I have only found a couple of pages that have displayed people's use of it. I think there is a way to set up a forum on a question/topic here. But, it should probably be done in StackOverflow. And, I don't know how to set up a forum/discussion.

Comment: If all you need is to retrieve a county name from lat/lon coordinates there is another API for that. https://geo.fcc.gov/api/census/#!/block/get_block_find

Comment: I did see a couple of government APIs for that. But, it would mean I would be running one request inside another. I wasn't sure how the timing in the code would work. But, I will look at that webpage and give it a try.  Is there a way to have the parameters I am passing come back in the data? In some cases I am passing the county code as a value. But, I don't know how to get it back to use along with the data.

Comment: If you are still having trouble it might be best to open a new question with a sample of your code.

Comment: I have typed up that question about counties a couple of times in my text editor; but, I never posted it. I kept getting ideas about how I might be able to get the counties. I should probably just type it up again, get my code and post it in StackOverflow.

Comment: If you want to run my web page, here is the question I posted in Stack Overflow along with a link to my code at GitHub.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446696/is-there-a-way-in-javascript-to-return-a-parameter-value-sent-to-an-api-with-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Min/Max values you're using are not of the county's actual borders, they are of its Minimum Bounding Rectangle (aka Bounding Box). That's the smallest possible rectangle you can draw which encompasses every part of the county. Here's a bounding box of Germany to illustrate:

[image]

Your min and max values are the limits of that red rectangle. So MinY is the southernmost point in Germany, MaxY is the northermost point, and so on. If you use those values to determine whether a point is within Germany, and your point is in the gray area, your program would say the point is in Germany even though it actually isn't.

So depending on the shape of your county (or state, country, whatever), the bounding box can be a really bad approximation of the limits of your feature.

Comment: I put the coordinates on a Google map. All of the county is included. But, some of the surrounding counties are also included inside:  https://imgur.com/a/mWvdvWH

Comment: Well, it was a fun exercise to code. And, I'm better at figuring out how to get data from an API. So, not a complete loss. Gotta look on the bright side.

Comment: @k-drive Yeah from your screenshot, any points located within that rectangle would be determined by your app to be in Cuyahoga county, even if they're in Lake Erie or a surrounding county. Bounding boxes can be very useful though: it's much faster to do a simple greater-than/less-than operation to determine if a point is within bounding box than to do a full GIS Intersect on a complicated polygonal shape. Bounding boxes are often used to narrow down a location to a smaller area before running more intensive processing.

Comment: Using the bounding box that way to save time makes a lot of sense. I was beginning to wonder why it was even defined.